# Fading Text on Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, fading

I've recently been put in charge of making a countdown page for a game launch. Now, I've got a simple countdown javascipt file made from [this tutorial](http://nithinbekal.com/2009/javascript-how-to-create-a-simple-countdown-timer/), but I'd like to make it a bit more fancy. I'd like to find some way to make the numbers fade out to the next one, just to make it a little less "jerky." Is there an easy way to do this? I've googled around and haven't really found a straightforward way.

Here's the JS:

```
function updatetimer() {
    now = new Date();
    launch = Date.parse("August 20, 2013 12:00:00");
    diff = launch - now;

    days  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60*24) );
    hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
    mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
    secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

    dd = days;
    hh = hours - days  * 24;
    mm = mins  - hours * 60;
    ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

    document.getElementById("timer")
    .innerHTML =
        dd + ' days ' +
        hh + ' hours ' +
        mm + ' minutes ' +
        ss + ' seconds';
}
setInterval('updatetimer()', 1000 );
```

And on the page there's simply an empty div named "timer".

Comment: "I don't think any code needs to be posted". You'd be wrong about that. Most users here don't enjoy going to a foreign site to sift through code. Please paste the relevant code here.

Comment: @j08691 : That comment was spot on!

Comment: I've updated it with the code.

Comment: Please don't so `setInterval('updatetimer()', 1000 );`, but `setInterval(updatetimer, 1000 );` or `setInterval(function() { }, 1000 );`.

Comment: To make it really pretty, you will want to crossfade two separate elements on top of each other - one fades in while the other fades out.  CSS3 transitions are fairly straightforward - [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/HPdAX/3/) that fades in and out, but you want a cross-fade effect which would combine two elements, and I don't have the energy to fiddle that out right now ;)

Comment: @Patrick I made a better answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the quick and dirty version using CSS3 with 2 elements cross-fading.  [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/HPdAX/4/)

CSS:

```
.readyToFade{-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
             -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
             -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
              transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.fadeOut{
           opacity: 0;
}
```

And the markup contains 2 elements.  The javascript here is ROUGH, but you get the picture.

```
function updatetimer() {
var el;
var el2;
if (document.getElementById('timer').className != 'readyToFade fadeOut'){
    console.log("yay");
    el = document.getElementById('timer2');
    el2 = document.getElementById('timer');

} else {
    console.log("no");

    el = document.getElementById('timer');
    console.log(el.className);
    el2 = document.getElementById('timer2');
}


console.log(el);
now = new Date();
launch = Date.parse("August 20, 2013 12:00:00");
diff = launch - now;

days  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60*24) );
hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

dd = days;
hh = hours - days  * 24;
mm = mins  - hours * 60;
ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

el.innerHTML =
    dd + ' days ' +
    hh + ' hours ' +
    mm + ' minutes ' +
    ss + ' seconds';

el2.className = "readyToFade fadeOut";

el.className = "readyToFade initial";

}
setInterval(function(){
    updatetimer();
},1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.The code is untested though.

```
function updatetimer() {
    $("#timer").fadeIn();
    now = new Date();
    launch = Date.parse("August 20, 2013 12:00:00");
    diff = launch - now;

    days  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60*24) );
    hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
    mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
    secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

    dd = days;
    hh = hours - days  * 24;
    mm = mins  - hours * 60;
    ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

    document.getElementById("timer")
    .innerHTML =
        dd + ' days ' +
        hh + ' hours ' +
        mm + ' minutes ' +
        ss + ' seconds';
    $("#timer").fadeOut();
}
setInterval('updatetimer()', 1000 );
```

Comment: Nah, this just causes nothing to show up. I'd put up the page but my host is being difficult today.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Jquery Fadeout

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. If you look at the code above, where exactly would this apply?